# relocate fixed comment at the top after old comments loads above jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this comments arrangement where a fixed comment is displayed at the top by default..

```
 <button>Show All Comments</button>

  <ul class="comments">
    <!--Ajax loaded hidden posts-->
     <li class="fixed">Fixed Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>

    <li>Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on "button" it loads pasts comments at the top and the `fixed` post is displaced down the list..

**QUESTION**

Using Jquery, How do I relocate this `.fixed` commnent again to the top once the button was clicked?

```js
$(document).on("click","button",function(){

//Show Ajax loaded hidden posts code
   $(".comments").prepend("<li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li>")


//requested code
   /* $(".comments").find(".fixed").append to new top?*/


})
```

```css
.fixed{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Show All Comments</button>
<ul class="comments">
     <!--Ajax loaded hidden posts-->
    <li class="fixed">Fixed Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (as you've pointed out) there may or may not be a `.fixed` comment present, we can't cheat by just inserting the new comments after the `.fixed` one in the first place.  Instead, prepend the new comments as you're doing, and then prepend the fixed ones onto the same node (which will automatically remove them from their original position in the DOM tree.)  This will work for any number of `.fixed` elements (including zero).

```js
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
  // add new elements:
  $(".comments").prepend("<li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li>")

  // rearrange the .fixed elements back to the top:
  $(".fixed").prependTo($('.comments'))
})
```

```css
.fixed {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Show All Comments</button>
<ul class="comments">
  <li class="fixed">Fixed Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, sound pretty clever, but in my real code I use this ajax: `$(".comments").prepend(data);`, sometime there is not `.fixed` comments so I cant make use of `$(".fixed").after(data);` anytime. How do I fix this? I think, in this case,  this is mandatory using  the parent `$(".comments").`

Comment: thank you my friend. pretty awesome approach. it works like a charm. Marked!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.prepend` use `.after` like the following. I also changed `$(".comments")` to `$(".fixed")`:

```js
$(document).on("click","button",function(){

//Show Ajax loaded hidden posts code
   $(".fixed").after("<li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li><li>Old Comment</li>")


//requested code
   /* $(".comments").find(".fixed").append to new top?*/


})
```

```css
.fixed{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Show All Comments</button>
<ul class="comments">
     <!--Ajax loaded hidden posts-->
    <li class="fixed">Fixed Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
  <li>Comment</li>
 </ul>
```